# Accelerate 2 loops with regex to find email address on website

Tags: python, html, regex, loops, web

I need help to find email adress on website. After some research, I found the solution but it's so long, I have a lot of datas (more than 90 000) and my code never stop.

Do you know tips to optimize/accelerate my code ?

This is my list of the URL:

```
http://etsgaidonsarl.site-solocal.com/
http://fr-fr.facebook.com/people/
http://ipm-mondia.com/
http://lfgenieclimatique.fr/
http://vpcinstallation.site-solocal.com
http://www.cavifroid.fr/
http://www.clim-monnier.com/
http://www.climacool.net/
```

I use 2 loops. The first is to find all pages of a website because the email adresse is not every time on the first page. 
In the second loop, I scrall the page to find the email address, the code :

```
EMAIL_REGEX = r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z])?\.)+[a-zA-Z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"""
```

I think my regex is too long, it can be a problem ?

```
session = HTMLSession()


mailing=[]
for index, i in enumerate(link): #link is the list of the URLs
    try:
        r = session.get(i)
        site=r.html.absolute_links
        linkslist = list(r.html.absolute_links)
    except:
        linkslist=list(i)
    for j in linkslist:
        try:
            r1 = session.get(j)
            for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, r1.html.raw_html.decode()):
            mail=(re_match.group())
            liste=[index,mail,j]
            mailing.append(liste)
        except:
            pass

print(mailing)
df = pd.DataFrame(mailing, columns=['index1','mail','lien',])
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: Why is your regex so long ? Can you explain what it does ?

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-scrape-email-addresses-from-a-website-and-export-to-a-csv-file-c5d1becbd1a0) (*"How to Scrape Email Addresses from a Website using Python?"*) may be helpful.

Comment: @SyKer I tried some Regex and this was the best to find email address

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank's for this link but this case only the url of the site is taken into account and not all the pages of the website. I already tried this technical...

Answer (score 0):

I think multi-threading should do the job. your regex, i don't know what it does but assuming its working and helpful, the multi-threaded version should look like the following. I tested the code, it works.

```
`from threading import Thread, Lock
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
lock = Lock()
link = ["http://etsgaidonsarl.site-solocal.com/",
"http://fr-fr.facebook.com/people/",
"http://ipm-mondia.com/",
"http://lfgenieclimatique.fr/",
"http://vpcinstallation.site-solocal.com",
"http://www.cavifroid.fr/",
"http://www.clim-monnier.com/",
"http://www.climacool.net/"]
linklist = []
mailing = []
main_threads = []
minor_threads = []
EMAIL_REGEX = r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z])?\.)+[a-zA-Z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"""




def links_scraper(single_url):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        r = session.get(single_url)
        site=r.html.absolute_links
        the_list = list(r.html.absolute_links)
        linklist.extend(list(zip([single_url for _ in range(len(the_list))], the_list)))
    except Exception as e:
        # print("Exception:", e)
        linklist.append((single_url, single_url))


def mail_scrapper(main_url, single_link):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        r1 = session.get(single_link)
        for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, r1.html.raw_html.decode()):
            mail=(re_match.group())
            liste=[link.index(main_url),mail,single_link]
            mailing.append(liste)
    except Exception as e:
        # print(f"Exception: {e}")
        pass

def main():
    for l in link:
        t = Thread(target=links_scraper, args=(l,))
        t.start()
        main_threads.append(t)

    while len(main_threads) > 0:
        try:
            with lock:
                current_link = linklist.pop(0)
            minor_thread = Thread(target=mail_scrapper, args=(current_link[0], current_link[1]))
            minor_threads.append(minor_thread)
            minor_thread.start()
        except IndexError:
            pass
        for t in main_threads:
            if t.isAlive() == False:
                main_threads.pop(main_threads.index(t))

    for t in minor_threads:
        t.join()

main()
print("Mailing:", mailing)`
```

Comment: Thank's @ShahidKhan for your help ! But with your code the list mailing is empty at the end... I tried to find solution but I couldn't....

Comment: @ThéaGilles I don't understand. I just run the code, it gives a non-empty mailing list. it has mails in it. can you recheck your code

Comment: In my list of links, the links are not between "" whereas in your code there are the "". Do you know how can I do to change my list ? Thank's again

Comment: @ThéaGilles i don't fully understand your comment but just take my list and you'll be good to go

Comment: I found solution, and your solution is very faster than mine, thank you so much. Just a problem: when i put a list with 5000 elements, your code print not all email. When I run again the code, this not the same results each time. For example, the first time I have results from 437th element to the 1067th element in the link list and when I run again the code I have from 543th element to the 1446th element. Can you help me ?

Comment: @ThéaGilles you can investigate the error by printing the errors catched in the try except blocks